# Does Mexico hold primary elections?

Tags: election, parties, primaries, mexico

If so, are they held by all national parties? For executive and legislators? And are party non-officials eligible to vote? If so, only members or open?

Note: Question is inspired by the nominating situation for Morena’s gubernatorial candidate in Guerrero.

Answer (score 4):

In Mexico elections are based on a single round of voting. With a plurality sufficient to win.

Parties register under Federal law (subject to certain requirements, such as achieving  3% of the vote or passing other tests of a certain minimum level of support) Then the selection of a party candidate is subject to internal party processes.

As an example, López Obrador was selected at the MORENA national convention in 2018.  There is no system for wider involvement in the selection of candidates, as in the (almost unique) primary system in the USA. Nor is there a run-off system, as used (for example) in France.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_Mexico
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Mexican_general_election
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Regeneration_Movement)

Comment: I’m trying to drill down into “internal party processes part”. Technically, I believe, us primary elections are also considered internal party processes for instance. Are those processes in Mx uniform? Q is prompted by AMLO’s statement that “ the people have already chosen” Guerrero’s candidate for governor and it should not be rescinded. I’m trying to figure out who those “people” are. Can’t imagine he’s referring only to party bosses in this case

Comment: I don't know enough of the details in this particular case. I note that for ALMO, there was 100% in favour, and he was the only candidate at the convention.  So in that case it seems the actual selection of the candidate was done by  "party bosses" and the convention was merely a rubber stamping approval.  US primaries are different, since they are organised by the state, not by the party.  This contrasts with (for example) the election of a Labour party leader, which involves a postal ballot of members, not a primary run by the government.

Comment: I can't find your quote, but ALMO seems to be quotes as saying "the people will decide", not "The people have already decided" (when speaking about accused rapist and MORENA candidate Salgado Macedonio.)